# Need Lua Help. attempt to index field 'Config' (a nil value) Gmod13

Tags: lua

Having this error when I run my gamemode.

> [ERROR]
>   gamemodes/rp/gamemode/**cl_init.lua**:910: attempt to index field 'Config' (a nil value)
>     1. unknown - gamemodes/rp/gamemode/**cl_init.lua**:910

`config` is a table, with index's such as `config["Run Speed"]` and the entire table is set globally equal to **GM.Config** in the **sh_config.lua** file.  Why is config not being registered as a value?  Must I include the config file into the cl_init file?  and if so, how?  Using the include()?

```
function GM:Think()
if ( self.Config["Local Voice"] ) then             **--Referred line(910)**  
    for k, v in pairs( player.GetAll() ) do
        if ( hook.Call("PlayerCanVoice",GAMEMODE, v) ) then
            if ( v:IsMuted() ) then v:SetMuted(); end
        else
            if ( !v:IsMuted() ) then v:SetMuted(); end
        end
    end
end

-- Call the base class function.
return self.BaseClass:Think();
end
```

Edit     --   config table in sh_config.lua.

```
local config = {};

   -- Command 
config["Command Prefix"]            = "/"; -- The prefix that is used for chat commands.
config["Maximum Notes"]             = 2; -- Maximum notes per player 
config["Advert Cost"]               = 60; -- The money that it costs to advertise.

config["Advert Timeout"]            = 150 -- How many seconds between adverts
config["OOC Timeout"]               = 60 -- How many seconds between OOC messages
config["Item Timer"]                = 7 -- How many seconds between item uses
config["Item Timer (S)"]            = 20 -- How many seconds between specific item uses
config["Note Fade Speed"]           = 12 -- How many minutes before nots disappear                                 

-- Voice
config["Local Voice"]               = true; -- Players can only hear a player's voice if they are near them.   This is the index being called which is creating an error.
config["Talk Radius"]               = 256; -- The radius of each player that 
--other players have to be in to hear them talk (units).

-- Player Stuff

 config["Walk Speed"]               = 150; -- The speed that players walk at.
 config["Run Speed"]                    = 275; -- The speed that players run at.


GM.Config = config;
```

I have                                  `includecs("sh_config.lua");` in sh_init.lua. `include("sh_config.lua")` and `AddCSLuaFile("sh_config.lua")` in init.lua. and `include("sh_config.lua");` in cl_init.lua.

Im still getting this stupid error though.  Can someone explain what the difference between including and Addcs'ing a file does.  How do I make sh_config's variables global in other files?  Or in other words how do I make the desired file(cl_init) read through the code in sh_config.lua and I can use code from it in the client side init?

Comment: Show the code responsible for setting `GM.Config`'s table as well as where this code is getting called.

Comment: Added code.  What do you mean where it is getting called?

Comment: @NickZook he means a snippet where you call `GM:Think()`

Comment: Another alternative could be the Lua Scripting part of facepunch.com - Seeing this is an official forum, there's lots of great GMod Lua minds there.

Comment: @NickZook - GM:Think() is called by the game itself. It's repeatedly called - Same with GM:Tick() - Tick begin 66 or 100 times/second typically. Think is even more than this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `sh_config.lua` at the top of cl_init.lua.

```
include("path/to/file.lua")
```

Be sure to do `AddCSLuaFile("path/to/lua.lua")` in the `init.lua` file as well. You will also need to do `include("path/to/file.lua")` in `init.lua` as well. (That's only required for shared files, though)

Also I am pretty sure the scope of your config table would be limited to sh_config.lua so you should remove `local` from your variable declaration.

Comment: That's probably a better way to go about it, I actually forgot. It's been a while since I developed in Lua for GMod. I guess you could do If SERVER then AddCSLuaFile("") end

Comment: And If CLIENT then include("") end

Comment: Yeah. In many gamemodes, "shared" is included in init.lua and include and AddCSLuaFile in cl_init. Files are then included in shared.lua and AddCSLuaFile() within a if CLIENT block.

Answer (score 0):

*sh_config* is a shared file - Meaning it'll have to be included both clientside, and serverside.

In *init.lua* - In **top** of the other includes. Put `include("sh_config.lua")`
Also in init.lua, put `AddCSLuaFile("sh_config.lua")` - This will make sure the file is downloaded by the client, and executed clientside.

In *cl_init.lua* - put `include("sh_config.lua")`. Also around the other includes. This should work as expected.

Seeing how this is a Config file, I assume it should be included first, or almost first. It may contain vital settings, for the rest of the script load.

Also - Often a shared.lua is included, to be equal to a shared_init file. This may be your case. If it is, you should add one `include("sh_config.lua")` with the includes, in shared.lua, and `AddCSLuaFile("sh_config.lua")` in a `if CLIENT then`-block

Comment: Where in cl_init.lua is the file included? above, or below GM:Think() ?

Comment: I included it at the very top.  Right under include("sh_init.lua"); like the 8th line.

Comment: Try adding `print("debug")` in the top of the configfile. See if it prints clientside when joining the server.